# onClick() to perform function?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick

Is it possible for in a form of username and password to perform JS validation with the onClick()?
Here is the code:

```
<form action="signup.php" method="post" name="formInput" onclick="validateForm()">
    Username: <br> <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
    Password  <br> <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I remember doing it before but cannot remember where to call the actual onClick() in the form creation or in the button submission?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You probably want `onSubmit()`.

Comment: Will the data even be validated before being sent to `signup.php`? I doubt it.

Comment: onsubmit="reuturn validateForm()" then return false or true inside the function

Comment: You would have to validate on a button, if it is valid then submit the form. If you try to do it on the `onSubmit' it will try to validate and then send it.

Comment: Thats the problem i have @Gendarme. It as if it isn't taking notice of the script i want to run first.

Comment: @JamesTaylor Why do you not do the validation in `signup.php` instead? That is the normal way of doing it, is it not?

Comment: @Gendarme how would that be done? with PHP validation? or can i just put the validateForm() at the top of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
   // if valid return true else false
}
</script>

<form action="signup.php" method="post" name="formInput" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    Username: <br> <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
    Password  <br> <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I have tried this. I also also tried adding a header to the validateForm() so it then goes to signup.php. Still to no hope.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the submit-button is clicked, `signup.php` gets executed and your `validateForm()` is ignored. I do not know why you are trying to validate the data with JavaScript instead of inside the `signup.php` itself. Furthermore it is almost certainly a huge security-flaw to do the validation on the front-end.

What I suggest you do is to forget about validating in JavaScript, and do it in PHP instead. If you post your `validateForm()` code we can help you translating it into PHP (and probably improve it as well).

**Edit:** You have stated that your validation is to make sure the input fields are not empty. So here we go:

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

if (strlen($username) < 1 || strlen($pass) < 1) {
    header(...); //redirect back to the home-page
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Username and password must be filled out.";
}
... //rest of your signup.php
?>
```

and change the extension of your HTML-page to .php, then add this to the top:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo("<script> alert('" . $_SESSION['message'] . "'); </script>");
?>
```

This seems like overkill for such a simple task, and probably is. However you will want to check for other things than the emptiness of the fields, and that has to be done in this way.

However, if you do not care and want a simple way to do it, you can probably disable the submit-button with JavaScript somehow until both fields are filled. Check if both fields are filled with something like `onChange = validateForm()` function.

Comment: okay. Here is the the validateForm() code:                                        `function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["formInput"]["username"].value;

    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Username and Password must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}`

Comment: @JamesTaylor Do you only want to make sure that username and password are filled? Not concerned with injection/XSS?

Comment: For my use no. This is purely a proof of concept at the moment and will worry for code injection at a later date. But suggestion for it would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @JamesTaylor I edited my answer. This should get your page up and rollin'.

Comment: I have put in PHP code but to no avail. I have 0 clue as to why now it does not work, when a while back i used it and it worked fine!

Comment: @JamesTaylor Does PHP work overall? Do you have PHP installed on your server? Can you share your `signup.php`? Perhaps you have an error there.

Comment: `<?php
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

if (strlen($username) == 0 || strlen($pass) == 0) {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Username and password must be filled out.";
    header("index.php"); //redirect back to the home-page
}
?>`

Comment: part 2:`<?php

$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
if (!$db) {
    die("Database connect failed: " . mysql_error());
}

$db_select = mysql_select_db("test", $db);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$pass = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']));

$sql = "INSERT INTO Dbusers (username,pass) VALUES ('$username','$pass')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($result) {
        header ("location:UniHelpindex.php");
    }
mysql_close($db);

?>`

Comment: @JamesTaylor When you say "it does not work", what is actually happening when click the submit-button?

Comment: it ignores the `validateForm()` completely, whether it is in the php file or as a separate JS file. I just think I'm missing something simple, such as having it on the correct part of the form or button. Idk. :(

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

`<form action="signup.php" method="post" name="formInput" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    Username: <br> <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
    Password  <br> <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" onsubmit="validateForm()">
</form>`